AI probing around
Yes, I am paranoid, and nowadays especially paranoid about AI-bots probing sites.
What would I do if I was developing AI?
I would test my creation on public sites.
Not without help. Captchas could be circumvented by human help.
What to do? Refusing honest human users on doubt cannot be an answer. Nor can it be that Bots infest not only this site but the Internet as a whole (they can emulate millions of users, once established at an indistinguishable level).
